# Understanding JDBC trace logs

Tags: jdbc, db2, monitoring, websphere-liberty

I enabled JDBC trace logging on my application. For a particular execute statement it logs

```
[jcc][Thread:Default Executor-thread-28][SystemMonitor:stop] core:
43832.056996ms | network: 43393.592823ms | server: 41240.041ms [STMT@927443182]
```

What does the `core`, `network` and `server` time indicate?
I am guessing `core` - is the total time. 
but then `core` != `network` + `server` time

Comment: This is not a standard JDBC feature, so you really need to add more information (what jdbc trace logging, which library, application server or other thing are you using for that, etc).

Comment: I am using DB2 driver. Application Server - Websphere Liberty profile

Comment: Which DB2 driver type and version? Which DB2 server version? Which liberty server version? Can you provide the SQL statement you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see IBM Knowledge Center Topic [System monitoring for the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvsysmn.html) for details on those fields.

In summary:

**Core driver time:** The sum of elapsed monitored API times that were collected while system monitoring was enabled, in microseconds. In general, only APIs that might result in network I/O or database server interaction are monitored.

**Network I/O time:** The sum of elapsed network I/O times that were collected while system monitoring was enabled, in microseconds.

**Server time:** The sum of all reported database server elapsed times that were collected while system monitoring was enabled, in microseconds.

Comment: So is the core time  not a summation of network i/o + server? I executed executeBatch() with some inserts. Total time which i logged in my application is equal to core time. Does the network time 43393.592823ms include server time? Which means for network i/o it took only 2153 ms.

Comment: No, core != network + server.  It may be easier to think of it like this, the timings are telling you how much time you spent in the jdbc driver (core), how long it took for all communication between driver and db to occur (network) and how much time was spent processing your request in the database itself (server).  The three times are provided because to optimize each of them requires different techniques and tools and knowing where to spend your time to obtain the most gain is important.

Comment: That means the total time taken by executeBatch() should be the summation of all three. But when I measured it in my application it is always equal to core time which gets logged in jdbc trace logs.

Comment: It would have been more accurate to say core is not always the sum.  Some driver operations can occur locally, this incurring no network or server time, only core.  Because core timing monitors the driver API, for operations requiring a round trip to db, the elapsed time in the driver API will include the round trip time, ie both network and system.